# Python pandas series: convert float to string, preserving nulls

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I preserve nulls after converting to string? I'm working with social security numbers, where it's necessary to go back and forth between float and string.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
x = pd.Series([np.nan, 123., np.nan, 456.], dtype = float)
x.isnull()
```

...Has nulls

```
y = x.astype(str)
y.isnull()
```

...No nulls

So ideally x.isnull() and y.isnull() would be the same.

I think it's dangerous to use a Series of mixed dtypes, but thinking this is the best solution for the time being:

```
z = y.copy()
z[z == 'nan'] = np.nan
z.isnull() # works as desired
type(z[0]) # but has floats for nulls
type(z[1]) # and strings for values
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast to to string, conditional on not being null.

```
x[x.notnull()] = x.astype(str)

x
Out[32]
0      NaN
1    123.0
2      NaN
3    456.0
dtype: object

x.values
Out[33]: array([nan, '123.0', nan, '456.0'], dtype=object)

x.isnull()
Out[34]
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This won't works if you converting categorical (int) to categorical (str).

And will do: `x[c.notnull()] = x[c.notnull()].astype(str)`

Answer (score 14):

I encountered this problem too, but for DataFrames. A method which works on both pandas Series and DataFrame is to make use of mask():

```
data = pd.Series([np.NaN, 10, 30, np.NaN]) # Also works for pd.DataFrame
null_cells = data.isnull()
data = data.astype(str).mask(null_cells, np.NaN)
```

Comment: I love this solution. Worked well for my data set with mixed data types. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the "string" dtype instead of str in pandas >= 1.0:

```
y = x.astype("string")
```

should preserve the NaNs.

It's described in the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

Comment: This one should be the top answer as this is the easiest and most "pandas way of solving"

Comment: The problem I run into with this solution is that all the null values are turned into "<NA>" when I later try to save it to the database.

Comment: So now I have object (str) columns with None values and object (Str) columns with <Na> (`<class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>`) values, why couldn't they just accept None as the only NA/NaN/NaI/NaD value... I think [the top rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779074/9530045) is better in this regard, since it allows you to set the desired "None" value yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert `np.nan` to `str`, it becomes the string `'nan'` which will be treated by `isnull` like every other string.

Regarding your edit: After converting to str values, you need to define, what strings are "null" in your opinion. One way to do so might be:

```
y.isin(['nan', '0', '']) # list contains whatever you want to be evaluated as null
```

This would at least give you the desired result.

Comment: I don't think I asked this clear enough. I want to preserve nulls, instead of converting them into `'nan'` strings. So ideally `y.isnull()` would be the same as `x.isnull()`

Comment: I think, you cannot use `isnull` for that purpose, however you could write your own method looking for all the string values that you consider to be `null`

Comment: Got it. It seems sketchy to have a Series of object dtype that's character for everything except the nulls, but I'm thinking that's the best option here

Comment: It's good but I'm more comfortable using pre-built `pandas` methods wherever possible. As long as I'm careful setting everything up, having mixed dtypes is something I can forget about downstream in my work, but having different ways of finding NAs will be arduous IMO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139539/discussion-between-mef-jons-and-arco-bast).

Answer (score 1):

Use series where to only convert non-null values to str:

```
y = x.where(x.isnull(), x.astype(str))
y.isnull()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, np.NaN is converted to the string 'nan' when you convert a series using `Series.astype(str)`, but not when creating a new series with `dtype=str`. So the following would work:

```py
x_str = pd.Series([np.nan, 123., np.nan, 456.], dtype = str)
x_str.isnull() # Has nulls as expected
```

Knowing this, we can use the Series constructor to convert an existing series to string while preserving null values:

```py
x = pd.Series([np.nan, 123., np.nan, 456.], dtype = float)
x.isnull() 
y1 = pd.Series(x.array, dtype=str)
y1.isnull() # Has nulls as expected
```

Just be aware that in order for this to work, you need to pass an array or list to the Series constructor (which, in the current example, means calling `x.array` or `x.values`). If you pass a Series, the null values will be converted as if you had called `astype()`

```py
y2 = pd.Series(x, dtype=str)  # x is a series
y2.isnull()  # Nulls converted to 'nan'
```